# Enable horizontal scroll in linear layout

Tags: android

This is my layout without scroll and the out is https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQeXd.png . Inside the "AlphebtesLinearLayout" I am creating listView dynamically. And still some portion is hidden at right so I need to go for Horizontal scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/AlphebtesLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

After adding horizontal scroll my output is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki86x.png the list disappears. Plz help me how to add horizontal scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/AlphebtesLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tamil_alphabets);


    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        LinearLayout AlphebtesLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.AlphebtesLinearLayout);
        int width=AlphebtesLinearLayout.getWidth();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams para=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/8,
                width/8 /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)*/);
        //list.setLayoutParams(para);
        createList(width);
    }
  public void createList(int width){
        map= new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2= new HashMap<String, String>();
        //--------------------------------------------
                final String[] Uirkeys = {"அ","ஆ","இ","ஈ","உ","ஊ","எ","ஏ","ஐ","ஒ","ஓ","ஔ","ஃ"};
                final String[] Uirvalues = {"a","aa","e","ee","ou","ou.","ay","ay.","ai","o","o.","ow","aak"};
            //----------------------------------------------------- 
                final String[] Uirkeys1={"க்","ங்","ச்","ஞ்","ட்","ண்","த்","ந்","ப்","ம்","ய்","ர்","ல்","வ்","ழ்",
                          "ள்","ற்","ன்"};
                final String[] Uirvalues1 = {"ik","ing","each","inj","it","in","ith","ind","ip","im","ye","er","il","ev","ill",
                           "ill.","er.","inn"};
            //------------------------------------------------------            
                final String[] Uirkeys2={"க","ங","ச","ஞ","ட","ண","த","ந","ப","ம","ய","ர","ல","வ","ழ",
                          "ள","ற","ன"}; 
                final String[] Uirvalues2 = {"ka","na.","sa","gna","ta","naa","tha","nha","pa","ma","ya",
                           "ra","la","va","la..","la.","ra","na"};
           //-------------------------------------------------------
            for(int loop=0;loop<15;loop++){ 
                if(count==0){
                    SelectKey=Uirkeys;
                    SelectValue=Uirvalues;
                }else if(count==1){
                    SelectKey=Uirkeys1;
                    SelectValue=Uirvalues1;
                }else if(count==2){
                    SelectKey=Uirkeys2;
                    SelectValue=Uirvalues2;
                }


                for(int i=0;i<SelectKey.length;i++){
                    map.put(SelectKey[i],SelectValue[i]);
                }
                for(int j=0;j<SelectKey.length;j++){
                    map2.put(SelectValue[j],SelectKey[j]);
                }
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams para=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/8,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        //para.weight=1;
        Activity activity = TamilAlphabets.this;
        TamilLetters=new TextView(TamilAlphabets.this);
        AlphebtesLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.AlphebtesLinearLayout);
        //AlphebtesLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        list=new ListView(this);
        list.setLayoutParams(para);
        GradientDrawable gd=new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setStroke(4, Color.BLACK);
        list.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
        ListAdapterTamil LstAdapter=new ListAdapterTamil(TamilAlphabets.this,map,map2,SelectKey,SelectValue,activity);
        String s=map.get("a");
        list.setAdapter(LstAdapter);

        AlphebtesLinearLayout.addView(list);
        TamilLetters.setText("aa");
        TamilLetters.setLayoutParams(para);
        //TamilLetters.setText(map.get(Uirvalues[0]));
        //AlphebtesLinearLayout.addView(TamilLetters);
        //count++;
        }   
    }
}
class ListAdapterTamil extends BaseAdapter{
    Context context;
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String,String> map2=new HashMap<String, String>();
private Activity activity;
String[] key;
String[] values;
    public  ListAdapterTamil(Context context,Map<String,String> map,Map<String,String> map2,String[] key,String[] values,Activity activity){
        this.context=context;
        this.map=map;
        this.map2=map2;
        this.key=key;
        this.values=values;
        this.activity=activity;
    }
    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return key.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tamil_alphabets, parent, false);
        TextView txt=new TextView(activity);
        LinearLayout AlphebtesLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.AlphebtesLinearLayout);
        AlphebtesLinearLayout.addView(txt);
        //txt.setText("ddd");
            //txt.setText(entry.getKey());
            txt.setText(map2.get(values[position]));
            txt.setPadding( 0, 0,0,50);
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `android:layout_height` to `"match_parent"` on your HorizontalScrollView and `"wrap_content"` to the width of your AlphebtesLinearLayout?

Comment: S I have tried but the same problem.

Comment: What is being put into AlphebtesLinearLayout?

Comment: I have posted the code above plz have a look at it..

Comment: I am adding 12 listView dynmaically..

Comment: Change your width calculation to be based on the HorizontalScrollView rather than the inside LinearLayout. The inside LinearLayout has a width of 0 if it has no children and you have it set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Only 8 are shown so I need to go for Horizontal scroll..

Comment: S got it thank u. Why if I specify calc width the list disappears when I added scroll?

Comment: It has to do with how you were defining your layout parameters. First iteration you had wrap_content for the height so that was 0 when you were trying to add the rows. Then when you changed the width of the LinearLayout to wrap_content it made the width 0. Once you had all of those in line it worked.

Comment: If you have your parent height set to wrap_content, and then set the content height to match_parent, you will end up with an issue on the first load. The issue is that you will have a parent container trying to wrap the height of an empty child (which means that the parent will have a height of 0) and then the empty child will try to stretch to match that height (which is 0). Thus a layout of height 0. After you dynamically add children or set the height, wrap content will have something to actually wrap, so the height will be whatever it needs to be to wrap that content.

Comment: I facing one more problem if I add horizontal scroll my list onitemclick listner is not working. If  I remove scroll item click is working.

Answer (score 0):

The `layout_width` of the `LinearLayout` that is inside your `HorizontalScrollView` should be `wrap_content`.